# Unable to read XLSX file content from mail attachmnet to store local drive

Tags: file, file-get-contents, xlsx

Below is the Java code we are using:

```
String contentType = message.getContentType();
String attachFiles = "";
// String saveDirectory = (String) resources.get(SystemRqstAppConstants.WebConstants.CUSTOMERITEMVENDORPO_PATH);
String saveDirectory ="D:/ResumeFiles/";
List<String> errorsList= null;
String messageContent = "";
logger.info(":::::Timecards Auto Update before Attchments:::::");
if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
    // content may contain attachments
    String client="";
    if(subject.contains("xxxx") || subject.contains("xxxx") || subject.contains("xxxx"))
        client="xxxx";
    else if(subject.contains("xxx") || subject.contains("xxx") || subject.contains("xxx"))
        client="xxx";                                                   
    logger.info("Timecards Auto Update client name: "+client);
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
            // this part is attachment
            fileName = part.getFileName();
            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
            saveDirectory = saveDirectory+client+"/";
            File folder = new File(saveDirectory);
            if(!folder.exists())
                folder.mkdir();
            String destFilePath = saveDirectory+fileName;
            logger.info("Timecards Auto Update destFilePath: "+destFilePath);
             FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);

            byte abyte0[] = new byte[4096];
            int length=0; 
            input = part.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
            while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(abyte0)) != -1)){
                 fileOutStream.write(abyte0, 0, length);
            }
            input.close();
            in.close();
            // my_xlsx_workbook.write(fileOutStream);
            fileOutStream.flush();
            fileOutStream.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: As it stands, this is not a good question. Please add some detail about the results of your code and what you expect. Also consider removing code that is not relevant to your problem. Read this guide on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on writing a question that will attract good answers.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your response and my question is simple that after download xlsx file attachment from email and store to local drive then need to read content and update into database, here we are unable to read the content from xlsx sheet which has stored in the local drive, for this have done so many R&D's to read the content, even used by Apache POI Objects and posted logic in the internet, any help on this that really appreciate. Regards, Rama

Comment: unable to save as the xlsx file by using the apachi POI Objects and other java logic and please help on this that really great appreciation. Regards Rama

Comment: Hi Michael, Please look into this issue and help on this "unable to save as the xlsx file by using the apachi POI Objects and other java logic and please help on this that really great appreciation. Regards Rama"